# Android button click doesnt register in fragment

Tags: java, android

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
View view;
Button button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headlines_view, container, false);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment2 = new ArticleFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

The onClick method fails to run when the button is clicked and I can't seem to be able to figure out.

Comment: What did you mean by onClick fails? It is not called or nothing happens? Usually, FragmentTransition is controled by parentAcitivity (which extends FragmentActivity or AppCompatActivity) and not by own fragment

Comment: I probably should have worded it better, but onClick is not called, even though the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
if (if (R.id.R.id.button== v.getId()) {
 //....


}            
}
```

//the following code must be added into activity using an interface

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment2 = new ArticleFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I can show you on chat if you do know how to do it.